# Accessing Elements returned by Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I inject a piece of HTML code dynamically inside a DIV on click using Jquery Ajax. After injecting i am not able to select the elements from this injected HTML. I need to write click events for these elements to change some data on the main page. If i write jquery inline i am not able to access the elements on the main page. Can anyone help?

My Jquery Ajax call

```
$(".template-2-column-std a").not('.emptyMessage').click(function () {        
    var parentidVal = $(this).data('parentid')
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Navigation/GetBreadCrumbList',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        data: { id: parentidVal },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        $('#breadcrumb').html(result);
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation to attach event listeners to elements that weren't on the DOM when the document loaded. Try this:

```
$('#breadcrumb').on('click', <selector>, function() {...});
```

I'm assuming $('#breadcrumb') exists when the DOM loads. Then you just use  to filter its descendants.

Comment: It also works if i place code inside success function

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('body').on('click','#myDiv',  function(){ 


});
```

instead of

```
 $("#myDiv").click ...
```

It's the way to access elements dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind you events in `succes` function, like:

```
.success(function (result) {

    $('#breadcrumb').html(result);
     bindEventListener();
})
function bindEventListener(){
  $("#newAddedElement").on('click', function(){
     do somethins...
  })
}
```